# Add scheme to URL if not present

Tags: java, http, networking, net-library

I have existing code that uses `java.net.URL` instead of `java.net.URI` all over the codebase.

Also, the code has URL parser that parses URLs appearing in some text body. All URLs that do not have a protocol prefix, such as www.google.com, are considered malformed when converting to `URL` object.

Is there a clean way to handle such cases in Java?

Comment: So, it appears that you have no record of the protocol of the URLs, correct? In that case, you just want to assume that everything is http, right?

Comment: yes and no. only when it starts with www

Comment: So the question is that you have URL's w/o protocols and you want to be able to handle them without rewriting all of your code?

Comment: Yeah - that's right. I was hoping for Java equivalent of C# URIBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Create a URI and see if it has a scheme. Set the scheme, or reconstruct the URI with a scheme argument, if not present. Convert to URL.